# Get the SelectedItem text in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using the built-in template for navigation Drawer in Android Studio.

I want to get the text of selected item from the navigation drawer menu.

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to modify the callback.

Inside `NavigationDrawerFragment` scroll to the bottom, and change the `NavigationDrawerCallback` to include a string:

```
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, String selectedText);
}
```

To pass this string, you'll have to modify the method `selectItem(item position)` to also take a string. Then in the `OnItemClickListener` in `onCreateView()` modify it like so:

```
mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView row = (TextView) view;
        String selectedText = row.getText().toString();
        selectItem(position, selectedText);
    }
});
```

Continuing on, modify `selectItem(int position)` to:

```
private void selectItem(int position, String selectedText) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position, selectedText);
    }
}
```

And now you have your selected menu text.